# Why SortedList.add() throws UnsupportedOperationException?

Tags: java, sorting, javafx-8

Very simple code:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;

public final class SortedListTest {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      final ObservableList<Integer> il  = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      final SortedList<Integer>     sil = new SortedList<>( il );
      sil.comparatorProperty().set((l,r)-> l-r );
      sil.add( 12 );
   }
}
```

Execution:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at SortedListTest.main(SortedListTest.java:13)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `SortedList` is a sorted view of its underlying list. If you were allowed to add elements to the sorted list it would break that relationship. You need to add the element to the underlying list instead:

```
il.add(12);
```

Comment: I have to give the sorted list to the TableView and keep the underlying list in my model. Operations on model are done on the underlying list when the views is sorted. How can I express an ordered constraint in the model?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand, but would it work to store an `ObjectProperty<Comparator<? super T>>` in the model (where `T` is the data type for the table), and (bidirectionally?) bind it to the comparator property of the `SortedList`?

Comment: @user2163960 Not quite sure the point of your comment: you do realize no one on here wrote Java, right? Your suggestion doesn't really make sense anyway, as a few minutes thought will tell you.